# Powershell - Compare CSV 1 to CSV 2 and then update CSV1

Tags: powershell

I am not looking for a writing service but please can someone point me in the right direction as I am completely at a lost as to how to proceed.

**Overview**
I have a CSV which contains a lot of data, some of which comes from a script and some in manually imputed.  I can run the script and get new data which is good. What I would like to do is find a way to compare the orginal CSV 1 to the new CSV 2 and update CSV 1.

```
Code I currently have 

$Vips_to_check = @{}
                 Import-Csv 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\Netscaler VIPs per Cluster_edited - Raw Data.csv' |
                 Where-Object {$_.PRD -match "No PRD code from VIP IP and VIP has no backend IPs" -or
                               $_.PRD -match "No PRD code found from VIP or backend IPs" -or
                               $_.PRD -match "No PRD code found from backend IPs" -and
                               $_.ipv46 -notcontains "0.0.0.0"}                                                 |
                                        
$Results_from_PIM = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\VIP-Owners_edited.csv'
```

Both of the CSV's have the same headers and layout which is good. I assume!

CSV 1

Name        IPV46      Port     Curstate       Suggested     PRD    Display Name     tech Owner    Slack Channel    Support Email

name 1     1.2.3.4    8080     Down     No      No     No     No     No    No    No

CSV 2

Name        IPV46      Port     Curstate       Suggested     PRD    Display Name     tech Owner    Slack Channel    Support Email

name 1     1.2.3.4    8080     Down     No      PRD123     TMOL     Gary     TMOL Support    Support@email.com    nsr.sys

I would guess at creating a hashtable but I just can't seem to get my head around the format of them. I tried

```
$ht = $Results_from_pim @{}
      $_.Name = (cant figure out how to reference the cell)
      $_.PRD = 
    $_.("Display Name") 
    $_.("Tech Owner")
```

Once I have the data in the hash table how do I overwrite the CSV 1 data?

Any points or guides would be great. I have tried reading up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.3 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3

But that left me even more confused.

At the moment the difference is only 4 or 5 entries and it would of been quicker for me to manually edit in excel but as this script gets larger I can see it being more time consuming to do manually.

As always thank you.

UPDATE

```
$ht = @{}
foreach ($item in $Results_from_PIM) {
          "name = $($item.name)" 
           "prd = $($item.PRD)"
           "Display Name = $($item.'Display Name')"
           "Tech Owner = $($item.'Tech Owner')"
           "Slack Channel = $($item.'Slack Channel')"
           "Support Email = $($Item.'Support Email')"
           }
```

I have created the hash table that I wanted from the CSV 2. Just got to get it to compare to CSV 1.

Update 2

Further to @theo request I have adjusted the question. Also to clarify When I want to merge the CSV it is based on matching the Name, IPV46 and Port on both CSV and then moving the updated data from CSV2 into CSV1.

Comment: You want to do a left outer join and use filename to combine the tables.  A Left outer is used when the number of rows in both tables are not the same and you may have items in table 1 that is not in table 2.  A normal join will only give results when both tables have common keys.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one

Comment: It would help if you can explain what field(s) should be used to _compare the orginal CSV 1 to the new CSV 2_ and what the desired output should look like. Please for that, [edit] the question and post the CSV1 and CSV2 lines in as [Formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) instead of images.

Comment: @Theo I have updated the question and done a formatted text as you asked.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for the link to the other question. I shall read through and see if that helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the code below (no extra module needed):

```
$csv1 = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\Netscaler VIPs per Cluster_edited - Raw Data.csv'
$csv2 = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\VIP-Owners_edited.csv'

$Results_from_PIM = Import-Csv -Path $csv2
$newData = Import-Csv -Path $csv1 | ForEach-Object {
    $search  = $_.Name + $_.IPV46 + $_.Port   # combine these fields into a single string
    $compare = $Results_from_PIM | Where-Object { ($_.Name + $_.IPV46 + $_.Port) -eq $search }
    if ($compare) {
        # output the result from csv2
        $compare
    }
    else {
        # output the original row from csv1
        $_
    }
}

# now you can save the updated data to a new file or overwrite csv1 if you like
$csv3 = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\VIP-Owners_Updated.csv'
$newData | Export-Csv -Path $csv3 -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. Please read about [Formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189)

Comment: Thank you for providing that answer. I am going to go back through it to understand and further my knowledge but I really appreciate you taking the time to come up with the code. I may end up having to ask questions if that is ok if I can't figure it myself or google it.

Answer (score 0):

After being direct to [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one) by @jdweng. I performed the following which seems to have meet my requirements

Install-Module -Name JoinModule -Scope CurrentUser

```
$Vips_to_check = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\Netscaler VIPs per Cluster - Raw Data.csv'
                                                               
$Results_from_PIM = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\VIP-Owners.csv'

$Vips_to_check | Update-Object $Results_from_PIM -On name, Ipv46, port | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221201\Final_data1.csv'
```

Going to do further testing with larger data sets but appears to work as required.